# I am trying to simply connect to the ibapi (Interactive Brokers API), but I am having some technical troubles with Flask

Tags: api, python-3.7, interactive-brokers, tws

I am trying to simply connect to the ibapi (Interactive Brokers API), but I am having some technical troubles with Python 3.7 .
What I did so far:

1. I installed the latest version for Windows 10 of the API
2. I ran `C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient` and run `python setup.py install`

I got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibapi'
```

when I try to import it 
What I am doing wrong here and how can I fix this simple error?

My flask project is created in a virtual env named Ibconnect ( (IBconnect) C:\Users\Admin\dev\IBconnect> on the command Windows )  and I think that I have to install the python client here but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use Anaconda - Spyder. In Anaconda prompt (just activates the conda environment) and navigate to the `dir C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient` and run python setup.py install